# 型が不定のクラスインスタンスを共通クラスに持つ方法がわかりません

Tags: c#, unity3d

各API用のデータクラスが複数あり、
各クラスのデータをAPI送受信のManagerクラスに渡したいのですが、
どのようにすれば良いのかがわかりません。

下記のように仮のデータクラスとしてTestAとTestBを作り、
APIManager内にどちらのインスタンスが来てもセットできる変数を作成したいです。

●testAクラス

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestA{

    int val1;
    int val2;
    int val3;
}
```

●testBクラス

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestB  {

    int val1;
    long val2;
    string valstr;
}
```

●ApiManagerクラス(シングルトン)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public sealed class ApiManager
{

    -----------------追記-----------------
    private APICommunicationThread ThreadOne = new APICommunicationThread();

    //　●●●●●●●●●●ここに不定なクラスのインスタンスを持ちたいです。

    private static ApiManager m_Instance = new ApiManager();


    -----------------追記-----------------
    /// <summary>
    /// スリープFLGを解除してスレッド再起動
    /// </summary>
    public void OnClickGoMessagePack()
    {
        ThreadOne.SleepFlgFalse();
    }

    private ApiManager()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Created instance.");
    }


    public static ApiManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Instance;
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething is called");
    }
}
```

-----------------追記-----------------

●最終的な処理の流れ
①各機能でデータ(TestAやTestBなどAPIにより異なる)を作成してもらい、
　ApiManagerの型不定のインスタンスにデータをセット、
　APIのURL、コールバック先のメソッドもセットしてもらい
　ApiManagerの通信スタート（スレッド再開）を呼ぶ。
②ApiManagerでは通信用クラスに型不定のインスタンス、APIのURL、コールバック先を渡し
　通信用クラスのスレッドを再開させる。
③通信用クラス内では型不定のインスタンスの型でシリアライザーを作成し、
　シリアライザーのPackメソッドで型不定インスタンスをストリームにパックする
④指定URLにPackデータを送信
⑤レスポンス取得後、中身のデータをコールバック先に渡す。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MsgPack;
using MsgPack.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;

public class APICommunicationThread
{

    private string MsgLog;
    public string SendUrl;
    public 不定な型 SendDataObj;
    public Type SendType;

    public Action<Object> CallBackTo;

    public Thread _threadFirst;

    public AutoResetEvent _threadEvent;

    public string TestString;

    public bool SleepFLG = false;
    public bool GoSendFLG = false;

    public void ThreadStart()
    {
        SleepFLG = true;
        GoSendFLG = false;
        _threadFirst = new Thread(ThreadWorking);
        _threadEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        _threadFirst.Start();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// スレッド処理
    /// </summary>
    public void ThreadWorking()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            // 現在、MessagePack処理をおこなっているか？
            if(GoSendFLG == true)
            {
                SleepFLG = false;
                GoSendFLG = false;
                // MessagePack処理
                MessagePackSend();
            }
            else
            {
                /// スレッド休止用FLGが立っているか？
                if (SleepFLG == true)
                {
                    TestString = "Sleep On";
                    // スレッドを給仕状態にする
                    _threadEvent.WaitOne();
                }
                else
                {
                    TestString = "Sleep Off";
                }
            }
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Msgpackを使用してAPI通信
    /// </summary>
    public void MessagePackSend()
    {
        try
        {

            MsgLog = "BEF SERIALIZE";

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            // --- シリアライズ
            // Set using Map instead of Array to serialize complex object. See Sample03 for details.
            var context = new SerializationContext();
            context.SerializationMethod = SerializationMethod.Map;

            MsgLog = MsgLog + "BEF SERIALIZE2";
            // 1. Create serializer instance.
            var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<不定な型>(context);

            MsgLog = MsgLog + "AFT SERIALIZE";

            // 2. Serialize object to the specified stream.
            serializer.Pack(stream,不定な型のインスタンス);

            MsgLog = MsgLog + "AFT PACK";

            byte[] bytes = stream.GetBuffer();

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SendUrl);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-msgpack; charset=UTF-8";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Accept = "application/x-msgpack";
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            MsgLog = MsgLog + "BEF GETREQ";
            // データの設定
            var s = req.GetRequestStream();
            s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            s.Close();
            // ***End your original code***
            MsgLog = MsgLog + "SENT";


            using (HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream st = wres.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int count = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            count = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                        } while (count != 0);

                        var deserializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<不定な型>();
                        // デバッグ用UTF-8 エンコード
                        string unpacktext = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

                        var unpacked = deserializer.UnpackSingleObject(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        CallBackTo(unpacked);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MsgLog = ex.Message;
        }

        /// 処理が終了したのでスレッド休止用FLGをたてる
        SleepFLG = true;

    }

    /// <summary>    
    /// スレッドを休止状態から起こす
    /// </summary>
    public void SleepFlgFalse()
    {
        /* スレッド処理を実行するようにフラグを落とします */
        SleepFLG = false;
        GoSendFLG = true;

        /* AutoResetEventオブジェクトをシグナル状態にして
            スレッドを再開させます */
        _threadEvent.Set();
    }

    public string DisplayLog()
    {
        return MsgLog;
    }
}
```

Comment: 変数を最終的にどう使用するのか分からないと答えづらいですが、`object`型で受け取ってリフレクションすれば大抵の事は出来ます。

Comment: Objectとリフレクションで検索したところ、
下記のような感じでできそうかなと思ってます。
サーバー側で中身が解析できるか試してみます。

Type t;
string classname;
t = Type.GetType(classname);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

Comment: その`Type.GetType(string)`にはアセンブリ修飾名という形式の特殊な型名を渡さないとダメですよ

Comment: 自分で作ったクラスの場合は、アセンブリ修飾名はクラス名と同一なのでしょうか？  
　string型の場合だと名前空間を足したSystem.Stringにする必要があるようなのですが、自分のクラスの場合どの名前空間にも属さなければそのままでCreateInstanceできました。

Comment: `Type.GetType(string)`は一部の場合「名前空間修飾名」でも実行可能で、その条件は該当の型が「実行中のアセンブリ」(自作クラスの場合)か「mscorlib」(stringの場合)に定義されていることです。言われている例では名前空間が未指定のため「クラス名」と「名前空間修飾名」が一致しているのでしょう。「アセンブリ修飾名」は`System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`のような値になります。

Comment: 試しにstring型でやってみようかと思って下記やってみたのですが、Activator.CreateInstanceのところでMethod not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() 　というエラーがでました。
　ウォッチ画面で見る限りSystem.String として認識されAssembly修飾名も入っているのですが、ちょっと悩んでます。

string abc = "def";
Type ttt = Type.GetType(abc.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(ttt);

Comment: Default constructorとは引数のない`public`なコンストラクターのことです。`string`型にはないので`Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`では使用できません。既定のコンストラクターがない場合例外が発生するのは多くのシリアライザーでも同様です。

Comment: msdn(https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)を見たところ、
おっしゃる通りstring型には引数なしコンストラクターがありませんでした。
そうなると、あらかじめ引数ありコンストラクターかそうでないかを知っておく必要がありますね。
チェックメソッドのようなものがないか内部のフィールドで判定できないか調べてみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### はじめに

データの送受信に関する、追加情報をいただけたので、その点に関して回答いたします。
尚、全開の回答と内容も範囲も大きく異なりますので、別の回答とさせて頂きます。

### 補足

尚、表題に関して、

> 型が不定のクラスインスタンスを共通クラスに持つ方法

ではなく、**不特定多数の型に対して、統一的な手法でデータの送受信を行う方法**を求めていると考えましたので、これ以降その仮定に基づいた回答をさせて頂きます。

### お断り

サンプルコードに関しては、

- 例外のハンドリング
- 各種ログの生成
- セキュリティ上の考慮

を全くしておりませんので、ご理解のほどお願いします。
また、

- Httpによる通信周りは割愛
- シングルトンだと都合があまり良くないので、staticメソッド化
- 非同期に関しては、Threadではなくasnyc/awaitを利用

しております。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MsgPack;
using MsgPack.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
public static class ApiCommunicator
{
    //鯖から戻ってきたデータをそのまま戻す場合（呼び出し先スレッドでデータを処理する際）
    public static async Task<T> MessagePackSend<T>(Uri serverUrl, T data)
    {
        var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<T>();

        //パッキング
        var serializedData = serializer.PackSingleObject(data);

        //送受信処理（ここでは遅延挟むだけ）
        var rcv = await SendMessage(serverUrl, serializedData);

        //アンパックして戻す
        return serializer.UnpackSingleObject(rcv);
    }

    //鯖から戻ってきたデータを指定されたコールバックに通す（戻ってきたデータを非同期的に処理する場合）
    public static async Task MessagePackSend<T>(Uri serverUrl, T data, Action<T> callBack)
    {
        //とりあえずデータを送って貰ってくる。
        var rcvData = await MessagePackSend(serverUrl, data);

        await Task.Run(() => callBack(rcvData));
    }

    //通信するスタブメソッド
    private static async Task<byte[]> SendMessage(Uri severUrl, byte[] data)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));



        return data;
    }
}

public class TestA
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    public int Val3 { get; set; }
}

public class TestB
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public long Val2 { get; set; }
    public string ValStr { get; set; }
}


public static class MainEntry
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sampleA = new TestA {Val1 = 42, Val2 = 84, Val3 = 127};
        var sampleB = new TestB {Val1 = 42, Val2 = 65536, ValStr = "hello world"};

        var server = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1");

        //データのみ受け取る場合
        var taskA = ApiCommunicator.MessagePackSend(server, sampleA);
        taskA.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("resultA.Value1:" + taskA.Result.Val1);

        var taskB = ApiCommunicator.MessagePackSend(server, sampleB);
        taskB.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("resultB.Value:" + taskB.Result.Val1);

        //コールバックする場合
        var task = ApiCommunicator.MessagePackSend(server, sampleA, x => Console.WriteLine("Val2:" + x.Val2));
        task.Wait();

        task = ApiCommunicator.MessagePackSend(server, sampleB, x => Console.WriteLine("ValStr:" + x.ValStr));
        task.Wait();
    }
}
}
```

処理の流れを拝見するに、シングルトンにする必要性と、あえてコールバックアクションとデータを保持する必要が無いかな？と思いましたので、このような形にしております。
もしコールバックアクションや、データを保持する必要があるのなら、ジェネリッククラスの利用を考えてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: なるほどー、MessagePackSend<T>はジェネリックメソッドと呼ばれるものでしょうか？  
T型のうまい使い方がまだあまり使い方がわかってないです。  
  
UnityのC#は.Net2.0までしか準拠していないためTaskとasyncとawaitを使用できないのですが、ジェネリックは使用することができるのでこちらのやり方をヒントにして少し考えてみます。  
  
コールバックのawait Task.Run(() => callBack(rcvData));　も何かに置き換えて使いたいなと思います。  
コールバック先にデータを返したい理由としては各呼び元がデータをどのように使うかを呼び先の共通クラスが意識しないようにした方がAPIを呼ぶ時に使用しやすいのではないかと思ったためです。

Answer (score 3):

### はじめに

user3732298さんのご質問を拝読して、**データクラスをマネージャ側で操作しない**と理解しました。また、データの送受信を行うとのことですが、その送受信の手法に関して様々なアプローチがあるため、その点は余談として軽くふれるにとどめます。
ただし、送受信をどのように設計するかは、どの程度まで不定にすることができるのか、逆に言えばどの程度共通化する必要があるのかと言う点に関わりますので、重要な因子であると思います。

### データクラスの構造が共通の場合

参考となっている、TestA及び、TestBは共に`int val1;`を持っており、コレが他のデータクラスにも当てはまるような場合は、インターフェース又は抽象クラスを使えば良いかと思います。
尚、インターフェースを利用するか抽象クラスを利用するかはケースバイケースなので両方を併記して、ここでは深く論じることはさけます。

#### インターフェスを利用する場合

```
    public interface IDataEnvelope
{
    int Val1 { get; set; }
}

public class TestA : IDataEnvelope
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    public int Val3 { get; set; }


}


public class TestB : IDataEnvelope
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public long Val2 { get; set; }
    public string ValStr { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ApiManager
{



    private static readonly ApiManager _instance = new ApiManager();

    //コレが不定なクラスのフィールドになります。
    private IDataEnvelope _dataEnvelope;

    private ApiManager()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Created instance.");
    }


    public static ApiManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething is called");
    }


}
```

尚、インターフェースを利用する際は、以下の制限が存在します。

- メソッド及び、プロパティの定義のみ可能
- 実装を含めることはできない

#### 抽象クラスを利用する場合

抽象クラスを利用する場合は、以下の通りとなります。

```
    public abstract class DataEnvelope
{
    int Val1 { get; set; }
}

public class TestA : DataEnvelope
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    public int Val3 { get; set; }


}


public class TestB : DataEnvelope
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public long Val2 { get; set; }
    public string ValStr { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ApiManager
{



    private static readonly ApiManager _instance = new ApiManager();

    //コレが不定なクラスのフィールドになります。
    private DataEnvelope _dataEnvelope;

    private ApiManager()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Created instance.");
    }


    public static ApiManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething is called");
    }


}
```

抽象クラスを利用する場合は、以下の制限が存在します。

- 他のクラスから継承ができなくなる
- 明示的実装ができなくなる

尚、抽象クラスを使うのがこのような場合では一般的ですが、非sealed＋virtual付きメソッド/プロパティでも実装可能です（但し、基底となるクラスがインスタンス可能となりますから、その意味はしっかり理解しなければならないと思います）

### 本当に不定の場合

本当に不定となる場合は、以下のような形になります。。。がデータの送受信を行う場合に共通操作が必要となることが多いと思いますから、いまいち使い道がないかも知れません（[Serializable]属性を使うことでできなくは無いでしょうが・・・）

```
    public class TestA
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    public int Val3 { get; set; }


}


public class TestB
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public long Val2 { get; set; }
    public string ValStr { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ApiManager
{



    private static readonly ApiManager _instance = new ApiManager();

    //コレが不定なクラスのフィールドになります。
    private object _dataEnvelope;

    private ApiManager()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Created instance.");
    }


    public static ApiManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething is called");
    }


}
```

C#では、いかなるクラス・構造体でもSystem.Objectを必ず継承するので、不定なフィールドをobjectとすることで、文字通り、何でもデータとすることが可能です。

#### 余談：どのようにデータを送受信するか

以下は余談ですが、データを送受信する際、シリアライズ・デシリアライズしなければ当然データのやりとりは不可能でしょう。
その際、データクラスの保持している値のみならず、元々のデータクラスの**型**も重要な情報になります。
また、どのような方法を使ってデータの送受信をするかは多岐にわたります。
一般的には、

- ISerializableインターフェースの利用
- Serializable属性の利用
- 自前でバイト配列化
- 自前で文字列化

等の方法でシリアライズして

- WCF
- Remoting
- 各種ソケットを利用して自前プロトコルスタックの構築
- ファイルに記録してファイルを送信する

等を使って送信・受信した上で受信後デシリアライズすることになるかと思います。
今回のご質問と直接の関係はないですが、どのような方法を使ってシリアライズ・デシリアライズするかで先に申し上げたように、設計の根幹にも影響すると思いますので、全体的によく考える必要があると思います。

Comment: シリアライズにはMsgPackを使用しており、
シリアライザーに型を渡す必要があるのですが
その際に型を指定する必要があり、その型もAPIによって異なり
Packする時には不定な型のインスタンスが必要がになります。

そして、そのPackされたストリームデータを、
HttpWebRequestでサーバーに送信しています。

その為、ApiMangerでは送信用の不定な型のインスタンスを
持っています。
通信が必要になった段階で各機能でデータを作成してもらって
ApiManagerにセットしてメソッドを読んでもらうつもりです。

文字数が足りないので質問の方に流れとソースをはります。

Answer (score 2):

> var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<不定な型>(context);

この`MessagePackSerializer`とは[これ](http://cli.msgpack.org/doc/html/AllMembers_T_MsgPack_Serialization_MessagePackSerializer.htm)でしょうか？であれば`Get(Type, SerializationContext)`というメソッドがあるので

```
var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get(SendDataObj.GetType(), context);
```

と呼び出すことが可能です。`deserializer`の生成も同様に`Get(Type)`を利用できます。その他の「不定な型」には`object`を指定してください。

なお`SendDataObj`が派生型であるとか`null`であるといった理由で別の型を使用したい状況も考えられます。その場合は`Type`型のパラメーターを追加して指定させるといいでしょう。

Comment: ＞MessagePackSerializerとはこれでしょうか？
そうです、ソースとしては(https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli)を
使用しています。

object型に関して質問なのですが、様々なクラスのインスタンスを
object型のインスタンスにセットした時、object型のインスタンスは
型セーフなのでしょうか？

Comment: @user3732298 すべての値型やクラスは`object`型を継承していて、安全にキャストすることができます。